# 'Software' keeps crashing after updating to 22.04 (June 8, 2022)

Tags: software-center, 22.04

I recently updated to 22.04, but now the 'software' app keeps closing without any notification whenever I click on a software to install. The update function did work fine. Very annoying, and unclear what the problem is. Does anyone know where I can begin my search for a solution?

Comment: Have you looked at system logs, like `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: hmm.. I get access denied?

Comment: Try with `sudo` or after `sudo -i`.

Comment: still permission denied. Sorry I'm not very capable in all this!

Answer (score 13):

**This answer is up to date as of June 8, 2022 at 15:56 UTC-04:00**

At the time of this post the Snapcraft upstream site (snapcraft.io) has admitted that there is intermittent availability and thus intermittent outages of the underlying Snapcraft site and inventory pages.

All the errors, crashes, etc. you are seeing at this time for the software store hard-crashing or snap store related errors or errors that are related to Snaps not being found are because the site - snapcraft.io - is having network/firewall issues right now.  Because the backend for the Snap store is unavailable, you are receiving failures.

Until a definite "This has been resolved" statement is made by Snapcraft, there is nothing you can do as the intermittent outages on their end are causing these errors.

**This answer is a canonical answer for the snapcraft issues posted within the past 24 hours regarding crashing after updating for software center, snap store, etc.**

Answer (score -3):

Well, if you already know the name of the package(s) you want to install, you could install them from the command line in the terminal, right?

```
sudo apt-get install <package name>
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: This allows you to install packages, but doesn't really answer the OPs' question about how to fix the software center from crashing.  Which is related to Snapcraft.  (And this won't work for snaps)